# Node 14 relative include

Tags: node.js

In a Node 12 .js file, I previously used this approach to successfully load a configuration file:

```js
const config = require("./config.json");
```

When changing to Node 14 with a .mjs file I adopted this:

```js
const config = JSON.parse(fs.readFileSync("./config.json"));
```

---

I have called both using this command (in a cronjob):

```sh
/opt/homebrew/bin/node ~me/Developer/su-squares/update-script/have-there-been-updates.mjs || say updates
```

And the behavior is different. The former loads the config file relative to the calling .js file. But the latter loads relative to the current working directory.

Is it possible to update the latter to adopt the preferred relative file path search?

Comment: You can use `import` instead of `require` (see https://stackoverflow.com/a/55910416/2740650).  But if you want to use the second form, try using `__dirname` to get the path to the executing script.

Comment: When using `import`: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_FILE_EXTENSION]: Unknown file extension ".json" for .../config.json

Comment: What is your CWD?